# Too many arguments for public abstract fun in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, dao

While making a to-do list for Android in Kotlin, I was trying to pass the "id" in the brackets but got an error. Also, the tutorial I learned it from was working fine and I am facing this issue. How to solve this problem?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEYL2.png)

I was to expect it to work fine. All other files are correct only this one has a problem. And for that reason, my app's not running.

My implementation of getATodoById inside TodoDAO -

[TodoDAO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cwax.png)

Comment: Please share the implementation of **getATodoById** inside TodoDAO.

Comment: The method getATodoById does not have any arguments, so you cannot pass it anything. If you want to pass it an argument, you will have to change the method signature. Similar to what you did in updateATodo and deletaATodo. Also, notice that the query you have for getATodoById and getAllTodos is the same. You should be adding a where clause to get the Todo by Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Pass simple parameters to a query](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#simple-parameters). You should pass `id` as an argument to both the method and the query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `todo-table` WHERE id = :id")
abstract fun getATodoById(id: Int): Flow<Todo>
```

Comment: Awesome! Please accept this answer if you've found it helpful - would appreciate it.